# php foreach statement to pull images, if none found replace with holding image

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, count

I am trying to run the following foreach on some images and it doesn't like my statement:

```html
<?php foreach ($images as $image) {
    if (count($images) > 1) {
        '<img src="'.$image.'" class="slide">
         <a href="#" class="zoom"><i class="icon-popup"></i></a>'
    } else {
        '<img class="slide" src="no-image-large.jpg">';
    }
endforeach ?>
```

Being a non-php guru, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: will you post the code which is pulling images. because if you check length of $images before foreach loop there is no need of loop when returned value < = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things here.

Firstly, you're mixing foreach syntax.  Either do

1. `foreach($a as $b) { code }`
2. `foreach($a as $b): code endforeach;`

Also, you need to echo out the string to the page, otherwise it's just a string in PHP, you're also missing a semi-colon on the first string.

```
<?php 
    $images[0] = "image1";
    $images[1] = "image2";
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        if (count($images) > 1) {
            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" class="slide">
            <a href="#" class="zoom"><i class="icon-popup"></i></a>';
        } else {
            echo '<img class="slide" src="no-image-large.jpg">';
        }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct.but you need to close your **foreach** loop properly.may this help you.

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image) {
if (count($images) > 1) {
    '<img src="'.$image.'" class="slide">
     <a href="#" class="zoom"><i class="icon-popup"></i></a>'
} else {
    '<img class="slide" src="no-image-large.jpg">';
}
} ?>
```